# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException When trying to export details from a database (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I'm currently working on a Computer Science A Level controlled assessment, in which I am building an application that is aiming to help leaders to manage their Scout groups.  This is my first time working in Android Studio, Java, sqlite or XML, so I've run into a fair few problems, this being the most recent.  I'm trying to create a function that will generate a random meal from a table in order to create a meal plan for an event.  Below I have put the code found in the databaseHandler Class:

```
//Select a random lunch
public Cursor getRandomMeal()
{
    String whereClause = COLUMN_MTYPE + "=?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[]{"Lunch"};
    String columns[] = new String[]{COLUMN_MEID + " AS " + BaseColumns._ID, COLUMN_MNAME, COLUMN_MTYPE, COLUMN_INGR, COLUMN_FCOST};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_FOOD, columns, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, "RANDOM()limit 1");
    return cursor;
}
```

Followed by the code on the class for the activity in which this function is called:

```
double TotalFoodCost;
    if (providingfood=true)
    {
        Cursor FoodItem = FoodDatabaseHandler.getRandomMeal();
        String FoodName = FoodItem.getString(FoodItem.getColumnIndex(FoodDatabaseHandler.COLUMN_MNAME));//error is apparently occurring here
        String FoodIngredients = FoodItem.getString(FoodItem.getColumnIndex(FoodDatabaseHandler.COLUMN_INGR));
        double FoodPricePerPerson = FoodItem.getDouble(FoodItem.getColumnIndex(FoodDatabaseHandler.COLUMN_FCOST));
        TotalFoodCost = FoodPricePerPerson*(31-ScoutsRemaining);//31 due to the head leader being included
        FoodDatabaseHandler.close();
    }
    else
    {
        TotalFoodCost=0;
    }
```

And finally, here is what the LogCat is showing when the error occurs:

```
01-25 18:27:08.785 29383-29383/com.example.atomi.scoutmanagerprototype E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.atomi.scoutmanagerprototype, PID: 29383
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5310)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5310) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696) 
 Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
    at com.example.atomi.scoutmanagerprototype.frmCreateEvent2.saveAndExit(frmCreateEvent2.java:154)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5310) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

I'm struggling, as I can't seem to work out how to fix this having read the error messages - if anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be fantastic.

Comment: You need to move the `Cursor` to a valid position before trying to retrieve data from it; e.g., `FoodItem.moveToFirst()`. You should also make sure that `moveToFirst()` returns `true` before pulling that data; e.g., `if (FoodItem.moveToFirst()) { ... }`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help!